# Orbeon Xforms development environment

Tags: orbeon

Is there a walk-through for getting Oxygen XML Editor set-up to create XForms for Orbeon deployment? The Orbeon FAQ http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-development-environment seems a little out of date (the schema links don't work).

Thanks

Comment: We don't have a better walk-through, but I fixed the links to the schemas, if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't much specific to the Oxygen editor to know about when writing XForms, and I would recommend you go through this [XForms tutorial](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/orbeon-forms-xforms-tutorial).

Comment: Thanks. The schema files under the corrected links were what I was after.